# error en sync await

Tags: javascript

```js
const insertNum = ()=>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const numUsuario = Number(window.prompt("Introduce un número (1 - 6):")); 
          // Pide al usuario que introduzca un número
        const aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1); 
          // Elige un número aleatorio del 1 al 6
      
        if (isNaN(numUsuario)) {
          reject(new Error("Tipo de entrada incorrecta")); 
              // Si el usuario introduce un valor que no es un número, 
              // ejecuta reject con un error
        }
      
        if (numUsuario === aleatorio) {
          // Si el número del usuario coincide con el número aleatorio, 
          // devuelve 2 puntos
          resolve({
            puntos: 2,
            aleatorio,
          });
        } else if (numUsuario === aleatorio - 1 || numUsuario === aleatorio + 1) {
          // Si el número del usuario es diferente al número aleatorio por 1, 
          // devuelve 1 punto
          resolve({
            puntos: 1,
            aleatorio,
          });
        } else {
          // Si no, devuelve 0 puntos
          resolve({
            puntos: 0,
            aleatorio,
          });
        }
      });
      
      const continuarJuego = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          if (window.confirm("¿Quieres continuar?")) { 
              // Pregunta si el usuario quiere continuar el juego
              // con un modal de confirmación
            resolve(true);
          } else {
            resolve(false);
          }
        });
      };
    }
      
      
      const suponer = async () => {
        try {
          const result = await insertaNum(); 
            // En lugar del método 'then', podemos obtener el resultado 
            // directamente, poniendo 'await' antes de la promesa
          alert(`Dado: ${result.aleatorio}: obtuviste ${result.puntos} puntos`);
      
          const estaContinuando = await continuarJuego();
      
          if (estaContinuando) {
            suponer();
          } else {
            alert("Terminó el juego");
          }
        } catch (error) { 
            // En lugar del método 'catch', podemos usar la sintaxis 'try/catch'
          alert(error);
        };
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    

    <script src="./numAleatorio.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Este codigo produce un error al momento de ejecutarlo. No encuentro donde está.Es un erro en el archivo de javascript. Al menos está bien escrito, no hay errores de sintaxis o escritura , es otro tipo de equivocación. Indica un error del tipo  Cannot redefine property: referrer , al buscar en google este error , tampoco encuentro una explicación muy clara.Po ello es que la envío . Espero se pueda solucionar y no resulte demasiado dificil. si bien tiene bastante código, es posible que ocupe algo de tiempo. también es un ejemplo de extraido de un tutorial , que no debiese tener errores , porque es un tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

te falta un poco de orden en el archivo de javascript, tienes mal un corchete, y una función no la invocas con el nombre, intenta con esto, pero mantén un orden, el editor te formatea el código.

```
const insertNum = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const numUsuario = Number(window.prompt("Introduce un número (1 - 6):"));
    // Pide al usuario que introduzca un número
    const aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    // Elige un número aleatorio del 1 al 6

    if (isNaN(numUsuario)) {
      reject(new Error("Tipo de entrada incorrecta"));
      // Si el usuario introduce un valor que no es un número, 
      // ejecuta reject con un error
    }

    if (numUsuario === aleatorio) {
      // Si el número del usuario coincide con el número aleatorio, 
      // devuelve 2 puntos
      resolve({
        puntos: 2,
        aleatorio,
      });
    } else if (numUsuario === aleatorio - 1 || numUsuario === aleatorio + 1) {
      // Si el número del usuario es diferente al número aleatorio por 1, 
      // devuelve 1 punto
      resolve({
        puntos: 1,
        aleatorio,
      });
    } else {
      // Si no, devuelve 0 puntos
      resolve({
        puntos: 0,
        aleatorio,
      });
    }
  });
}

const continuarJuego = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    if (window.confirm("¿Quieres continuar?")) {
      // Pregunta si el usuario quiere continuar el juego
      // con un modal de confirmación
      resolve(true);
    } else {
      resolve(false);
    }
  });
};

const suponer = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await insertNum();
    // En lugar del método 'then', podemos obtener el resultado 
    // directamente, poniendo 'await' antes de la promesa
    alert(`Dado: ${result.aleatorio}: obtuviste ${result.puntos} puntos`);

    const estaContinuando = await continuarJuego();

    if (estaContinuando) {
      suponer();
    } else {
      alert("Terminó el juego");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // En lugar del método 'catch', podemos usar la sintaxis 'try/catch'
    alert(error);
  };
}


suponer()
```

Comment: Ok. gracias por tu respuesta. Lo que pasa ahora es que aparece que la función continuar juego no está definida

Comment: Yo lo copié tal cual y me funcionaba